# How to Publish files from a Pull request

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I am trying to publish the files which are changed in pull request.
I have written a PowerShell to find the difference in two branches Source and Target.

```
$sourceBranch = $env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH.Replace('refs/heads/', '')
$targetBranch = $env:SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH.Replace('refs/heads/', '')
$remoteRepo = git config --get remote.origin.url
$changedFiles = git diff --name-only origin/$targetBranch...origin/$sourceBranch
foreach ($file in $changedFiles) {
    $artifactName = Split-Path -Path $file -Leaf
    Publish-BuildArtifact -Path $file -ArtifactName $artifactName -ItemType File
}
Write-Host "Changed files:"
foreach ($file in $changedFiles) {
    Write-Host $file
}
```

however I am getting below error while execution

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\a5005eb5-c39e-433d-adfe-648dc3c6926f.ps1'"
fatal: '-' is not a valid branch name
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master...origin/Prtestdemo': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Changed files:
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

I am executing the script in Azure Build Pipeline
The Task which is used is PowerShell and the agent is Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2019

can you please let me know what is getting wrong?

Comment: The code you're showing wouldn't explain the `fatal: '-' is not a valid branch name` error message. As an aside: it's simpler and more robust to use `-File` to invoke a script file via the CLI: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "D:\a\_temp\a5005eb5-c39e-433d-adfe-648dc3c6926f.ps1"`

Comment: @mklement0 : Thanks for the Reply.
However, there is nothing wrong with the Powershell Task. It's something wrong with the command `git diff --name-only origin/$targetBranch...origin/$sourceBranch`

Answer (score 0):

Use builds without shallow fetch:

For classic:

[image]

For yaml:

[steps.checkout Shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch)

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```